# App with Imageview scale in Android Studio emulator Small Device breaks without error

Tags: android-emulator, imageview, zooming, abort

I have an App that loads a Bitmap in a ImageView using the Android Studio Emulator with a Small Device.

When I execute a Zoom function by Matrix setScale it brakes without giving any Exception. I tried using a Try/catch coding and I have a default catch Thread in the app but it does not work.

I use the exact same code with a Medium Device and others but they work nicely, only the Small Device brakes.

The suspect error is the one immediately after the last Zoom code [Unable to match the desired swap behavior.] in the Logcat.  Maybe something with the Matrix operation generates an internal error but is not making a catchable Exception.

How do I solve this?

Here is my Zoom function:

```
slider.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, _ ->
        // Responds to when slider's value is changed
        try {
            tv = "Zoom Value:\n${value.format(2)}%"
            zoom.text = tv

            scaleX = 1 + value / 100
            scaleY = 1 + value / 100

            slidervalue = value
            val f = FloatArray(9)
            m.getValues(f)

            scrollX = f[Matrix.MTRANS_X]
            scrollY = f[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]
            pscrollX = scrollX
            pscrollY = scrollY

            Log.d("Before scale", "Before scale")
            m.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, centerX, centerY)
            Log.d("Before scale", "After matrix scale")
            val bounds: RectF = getImageBounds(pdfview, m)
            pdfview.imageMatrix = m
            Log.d("Before scale", "After view set")

            
            val pbounds: RectF = getImageBounds(pdfview)
            Log.d("Slider p bounds", pbounds.toString())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("Slider Error", e.message.toString())
        }

    }
```

Default exception Tread:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        //Log.d("Force Exit", e.stackTrace.toString())
        Toast.makeText(
            this@MainActivity,
            "Application Terminated ${e.message.toString()}",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
        exitProcess(2)
    }
```

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image_border"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linear"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hidden" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pdfview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pdf"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:srcCompat="@color/material_dynamic_neutral80" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frame"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/zoomvalue"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="300.0"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/zoom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:text="@string/zoom_value"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slider"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/autoCenter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_border"
            android:checked="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:tag="true"
            android:text="@string/pan_center"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:tooltipText="@string/move_image_to_the_center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:checked="false"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switchReset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_border"
            android:checked="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:tag="true"
            android:text="@string/reset"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:tooltipText="@string/undo_last_pan"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:checked="false"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/clearpdf"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_border"
            android:checked="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:tag="true"
            android:text="@string/clear_pdf"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:tooltipText="@string/remove_pdf_to_look_for_another"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:checked="false"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The View looks:

[image: The view with a Bitmap]

When breaks notice the App is still running according to the debugger but the Emulator no longer shows the View:

[image]

Logcat:

```
Before scale            com.mastering.pdfactivity            D  
Before scale
Before scale            com.mastering.pdfactivity            D  
After matrix scale
Before scale            com.mastering.pdfactivity            D  
After view set
Slider m bounds         com.mastering.pdfactivity            D RectF(-137.2351, -167.19812, 737.2351, 898.1981), cX=300.0, cY=365.5, msx=-118.85547, msy=-144.8056
Slider p bounds         com.mastering.pdfactivity            D  RectF(-137.2351, -167.19812, 737.2351, 898.1981)
3956-3956  A                       com....android.googlequicksearchbox  I  onApplyWindowInsets: systemWindowInsets=Insets{left=0, top=48, right=0, bottom=48}
3956-3956  A                       com....android.googlequicksearchbox  I  onApplyWindowInsets: systemWindowInsets=Insets{left=0, top=48, right=0, bottom=48}
3956-4118  OpenGLRenderer          com....android.googlequicksearchbox  E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
1131-1921  OpenGLRenderer          com...le.android.apps.nexuslauncher  E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
```